# Как выбросить исключение, не прервав цикл While

Tags: java, исключения, циклы, while, стек

Написана программа, которая добавляет и удаляет элементы из Стека по команде, которую ввёл пользователь. Дело в том, что если вместо цифры на ввод написать любой символ, например "а", то программы выдаст InputMismatchException. 
Вот код программы:

```
class Main {

public static void showpush(Stack st, String a)
{
    st.push(new String(a));
    System.out.println("Добавлен(" + a + ")");
    System.out.println("Стек: " + st);
}
public static void showpop(Stack st)
{
    if (st.empty())
        System.out.println("Вы пытаетесь извлечь элемент из пустого стека");
    else {
        System.out.print("Удалён элемент -> ");
        String a = (String) st.pop();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("Стек: " + st);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("На ввод команды приниются только цифры");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack st = new Stack();
    System.out.println("Стек: " + st);
    int komanda=0;
    try {
        while (komanda != 666) {
            System.out.println("Чтобы добавить элемент в стек напишите 1, чтобы извлечь - 2, остановить - 666");

            komanda = sc.nextInt();

            if (komanda == 1) {
                String dobav;
                System.out.println("Введите элемент: ");
                dobav = sc.next();
                showpush(st, dobav);
            } else if (komanda == 2) {
                showpop(st);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("На ввод принимаются только цифры");
    }
    System.out.println("Процесс остановлен");
}
}
```

Пробовал ловить InputMismatchException внутри цикла, но когда выводится ошибка, цикл начинает работать бесконечно, т.к. переменную мы уже задали. А если вынести ***try / catch*** за цикл While, то после срабатывания цикл прекращает работать, а хотелось бы, чтобы пользователю снова предоставлялась возможность ввода команды.

Comment: " т.к. переменную мы уже задали" - какую?

Comment: Переменная задаётся с клавиатуры в строке                 komanda = sc.nextInt();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `scanner.nextInt()` проверьте есть ли там целое значение методом `scanner.hasNextInt()` - это позволит не ловить исключение, не говоря уже о том, что перехват исключения довольно дорогая операция, да и некрасивая она :)

**Update**

Примерно так:

```
if(!sc.hasNext())  //чтобы не было вечного цикла
   break;
if(sc.hasNextInt())  //проверяем есть ли целое число
   komanda=sc.nextInt();  //читаем
else {
   komanda=0;
   continue; //продолжаем цикл
}
```

Comment: А как на примере моего кода это реализовать? Не совсем понял. Если убрать try/cacth и написать sc.hasNextInt(); перед komanda = sc.nextInt();  то ничего не выходит

Comment: вы вообще умеете прогать? См. апдейт

Comment: Только в этом семестре начал Java учить, так что не сказал бы

Comment: причем тут Java - язык не играет роли, учили же наверное в школе паскалю или питону?

Comment: В школе был паскаль, но знания по нему в итоге были довольно посредственные. Серьезно стал к этому относиться, как только в вуз поступил

Comment: Вставил ваш код в цикл, при вводе любой буквы цикл начинает бесконечно выводить сообщение о вводе команды

Comment: Исправил код. по хорошему надо бы условие цикла `while` менять типа: `while(komanda!=666 || sc.hasNext())`

Comment: Попробовал изменить условие While, просто выдаётся красный Exception, который я изначально хотел обработать.(Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException)  А исправленный отрывок кода всё равно при вводе буквы запускает бесконечный цикл  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯       Изменил !sc.hasNext на !sc.hasNextInt, цикл не бесконечный, но после ввода буквы он останавливается

Comment: Мне это начинает надоедать - я как бы не подряжался за вас писать код. Вы просто продумайте всю логику сами - я же пишу на коленках, а у вас есть отладчик, IDE и все такое. Спойлер: проверку `sc.hasNext()` надо заносить в ветку `else`, а условия `while()` надо чуток переформулировать. в общем на этом все - удачи!

Comment: мало пропустить итерацию если следующий токен - не число, надо еще вычитать этот токен.